# Python- fit logarithmic model courve on a data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, logarithm

I want to fit better my model to my data. Now I use this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as sc

x_value=np.array([30000,27850,25590,23900,22400,20470,19450,18120,17130,16180,15340,14620,13730,13400,12790,12460,12060,11760,11440,11200,10940,10780,10720,10530])
y_value =np.array([23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0])
p = np.polyfit( y_value, np.log10((x_value)), 1)

# Convert the polynomial back into an exponential
a = 10**(p[1])
le=len(x_value)
a= a+(x_value[le-1]-a)
b = p[0]
x_fitted_polyfit = np.linspace(np.min(y_value), np.max(y_value), 24)
y_fitted_polyfit = a * 10**(b * x_fitted_polyfit+np.min(y_value))
plt.scatter( y_value, x_value, label= "zisk", color= "blue", marker= "x",s=30)
plt.plot(  x_fitted_polyfit,y_fitted_polyfit,  'r', label='polyfit - unweighted')

plt.xlabel('frekvence [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('zisk [dBm]')
# plot title
plt.title('My scatter plot!')
# showing legend
plt.legend()
```

My exit is now this graph [image]
I have ready tried

```
popt, pcov = sc(lambda t, a, b: a * np.exp(b * t),y_value , x_value)
# Extract the optimised parameters
a = popt[0]+1000
b = popt[1]

x_fitted_curve_fit = np.linspace(np.min(y_value ), np.max(y_value ), 10000)
y_fitted_curve_fit = a * np.exp(b * x_fitted_curve_fit)
```

but it looks similar.

Comment: Are you sure there are no confution between x and y here? `x_value` looks like frequencies, and `y_value` looks like dB. But then you are using polyfit to find how to compute `log(x)` from y. So, `log(freq)` from dB. Then, when applying model, you say that x goes from `min(y)` to `max(y)`. That's strange. Then you scatter plot reality x vs y. But plot model y vs x. So, my direct question is: do you know what you are doing, or did you just swap x and y everywhere, until it looks a little bit like fitting?

Comment: No pun intended. I just need to know whether your problem is about fitting, or more about trying to use it.

Comment: i had probleme to plot graf whit walues on x and y axis corespodet whit the names of value for that reason i change axis but stil had same name. Now i stil have problem whit plottin first version of a graf but i donot have problem whit ploting x_value for y_axis and y_vlu for x_axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seems to be assuming that model is
`x = a·exp(b·y)+10000` (that is what you've tried in both code, putting the 10000 in the wrong place in the first, and replacing it by 1000 in the second)

The closest working thing I can get from your code is

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as sc

x_value=np.array([30000,27850,25590,23900,22400,20470,19450,18120,17130,16180,15340,14620,13730,13400,12790,12460,12060,11760,11440,11200,10940,10780,10720,10530])
y_value =np.array([23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0])
plt.scatter( y_value, x_value, label= "zisk", color= "blue", marker= "x",s=30)

# We are searching x = a*exp(b*y) + 10000
popt,pcov=sc(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t), y_value, x_value-10000)
# Or, 
popt,pcov=sc(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t)+10000, y_value, x_value)
a=popt[0]
b=popt[1]
yf = np.linspace(0,23,24)
xf = a*np.exp(b*yf)+10000
plt.plot(yf, xf,  'r', label='curvefit')

# Same with polyfit. x=a*exp(b*y)+10000
# => x-10000 = a*exp(b*y)
# => log(x-10000) = log(a) + b*y. 
# So, what α β are such as log(x-10000) = αy + β?
# Then, β=log(a) => a=exp(β)
# And b=α
p=np.polyfit(yf, np.log(xf-10000), 1)
aa=np.exp(p[1])
bb=p[0]
xf2=aa*np.exp(bb*yf)+10000
#plt.plot(yf, xf2, 'g', label='polyfit')
# Some shift so that we see both curve (otherwise they are too identical)
plt.plot(yf-0.1, xf2+100, 'g', label='polyfit')

plt.xlabel('frekvence [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('zisk [dBm]')
# plot title
plt.title('My scatter plot!')
# showing legend
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I trace here 2 estimation of the same model. I had to shift the result a bit, because otherwise we cannot see both. Which is good. That means that, as expected, it is almost exactly the same result.

The first one is using `curve_fit`.
This one is straigthforwad. `curve_fit` does the thinking for you (but because of that, when you know what you are doing, it may fails, while you wouldn't).
You think that `x=a·exp(b·y) + 10000`, so just `curve_fit` that

```py
popt,pcov=sc(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t)+10000, y_value, x_value)
```

And then `a=popt[0]` and `b=popt[1]`.

Second method is with polyfit (linear regression in this case).

If you assume `x=a·exp(b·y)+10000`, then 
`x-10000=a·exp(b·y)`. So, with log
`log(x-10000)=log(a) + b·y`

So `log(x-10000) is a polynomial from` y`.

So

```py
p=np.polyfit(yf, np.log(xf-10000), 1)
```

And then `p[0]` is b, and `p[1]` is `log(a)`. Or said otherwise, `a=exp(p[1])`

Both case works as intended.

Not a perfect model. But that was your choice to assume the `10000` part (well, in you first code, you said the equivalent of 10530, but it was not better).

[image]

If you need a better match, for example, letting the optimizer find the `10000` part, then you need to

```py
popt,pcov=sc(lambda t,a,b,c: a*np.exp(b*t)+c, y_value, x_value)
plt.plot(yf, popt[0]*np.exp(popt[1]*yf)+popt[2], 'y', label='curve 3 params')
# It seems that best estimation of c is not 10000 but 9082
```

[image]

And in this case, I don't think you can do it with polyfit: there is no polynomial of degree 2 linking a function of x to a function of y.

Comment: Of course the fitting of the power function is better with a shift on the vertical axis. It is even better with two shifts : one (of -16.9) on the horizontal axis and one (of +10280.) on the vertical axis.

Comment: Thank you for this answer that was really helpful. Now i wont to plot this graf whit original axis. Theat mean i wont x_values on x_axis and y_value on y_axis. This version of graf had in my kase problem whit ploting and program runs ower the time RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power and do not plot. for that reason i firstly poust the first version hear.

Answer (score 1):

I guess two possible causes for the discrepancy of your result :

- Confusion between x and y in the code versus data, as already mentioned in chrslg's comment.
- Model function not well convenient. The simple power function might be not sufficient. I suggest to consider some shifts (a) on y and (c) on x as shown in the model function below which appears much better.

[image]